# Execute Command with sudo Node Webkit

Tags: node.js, npm, sudo, node-webkit

I found this on the npm site and installed it on my machine.
https://www.npmjs.org/package/sudo

but when I installed it and copy/pasted the example code they had, nothing showed up, no errors, no prompt, no output, nothing. Since there is little documentation to go with this I was wondering if anyone has any insight into the correct usage of sudo running on node webkit.